# How to change or disable software update policy on OS X Yosemite

Tags: osx-yosemite, imac

I once took my personal iMac to work and enterprise policy settings have been downloaded unto it. I am trying to download the OS X EL Capitan beta and I keep getting the software update policy on the mac will not allow it. I would like to disable this setting as it is my private mac, but I have no idea how to or where to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Administrators use **Configuration Profiles** in Mac OS X to standardize settings & behaviour.

A configuration profile can contain settings for configuring a user’s Mail account, Wi-Fi settings, VPN settings, and more.

**To view installed configuration profiles**

1. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, and then click Profiles.

[image: Mac os X profiles]

2. View the list of profiles installed & their details as shown

[image]

3. To remove the profiles, select the it & click (-)

*As you said this is your personal computer. Assuming you didn't do anything of this sort, you should be good to remove all the profiles listed & restart the computer to bring the changes in effect*

Comment: Thanks The_IT_Guy  I have checked its actually there with a profile called Block OS X Beta releases. Unfortunately when I click on it, the remove button is disabled. Looks like I might have to take my iMac all d way in to work to have this removed. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried booting into **safe mode**/booting while holding shift & removing it ?

Comment: @Bola, also you can refer to [this post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/98189/90381)